# MediaPlayer skips files if previous music file is short in length

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a music service class in which I have a method called `playNext()`.

```
public void playNext() {
    setSong(songPosn + 1);
    playSong();
}
```

and the `playSong()` method is,

```
public void playSong() {

    if(player != null){
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            player.stop();
        }
    }

    //play a song
    isPaused = false;
    isComplete = false;
    isPrepared = false;
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    //get song
    Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
    //get id
    long currSong = playSong.getID();
    //set uri
    Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            currSong);

    try {
        player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }

    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is when a song is played which has a very short length, `player` skips more than 1 song in the `songs` list. Even though, only 1 is incremented in the `playNext()` method.

Note: It doesn't happen every time. But most of the time. I cannot figure out the problem. And that short music file is a Facebook pop up sound which is less than 0 second in duration.